# react nested Route issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have the following code -

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import MainBar from './MainBar';
import Home from './Home';
import {Router, Route, Redirect, Link} from 'react-router'


class Main extends Component {

    render() { 
        return (
            <div className="container-home">
                    <MainBar/>
                <Route path='/main/home' component={Home}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Main;
```

The main routering inside app.js file -

```
   render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                {(this.state.loggedIn) ?
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/main" component={Main}/>
                        <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                        <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
                        <Redirect exact from="*" to="/Main"/>
                    </Switch>
                    :
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
                        <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
                        {/*comment on next line !!*/}
                        <Route path="/main" component={Main}/>
                        <Redirect exact from="*" to="/login"/>
                    </Switch>
                }
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
```

When the user enters the `'/main'` url he can view this component.
but for some reason when typing `'/main/home'` the nested components is still unavailable.
Some problem with the way i wrote the url?

Comment: Can you post the outer `Router`? In any case, I believe you're missing an `exact` prop in the `/main` route.

Comment: this is not how you must use `Route` in react, best practices suggest wrapping them inside a `Router` in another file and then rendering the component where you need it as a child of the main component. i.e. `<App>`

Comment: Though your routes are weird (using two conditional switches is weird), I do not think there is problem with your codes. Could you share `MainBar.js` and `Home.js`?